# ImportError in blpapi python for bloomberg

Tags: python, macos-mojave, blpapi

I am trying to get the BLOOMBERG API to work via Python on mac os mojave 10.14.

I have python 2.7.10 on my mac

I downloaded the C/C++ SDK Experimental Release v3.13.1.1 I unzipped contents to

> \Users\hk\blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1

I set the environment variables in .bash_profile BLPAPI_ROOT and DLYD_LIBRARY PATH as the C/C++ SDK path.

I then installed the Python API through pip as stated at the bottom of this page: [API Library Support](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/)
and received a **Successfully installed message.**

when using import blpapi I get the following errors:

```
File "blpapitest.py", line 5, in <module>
import blpapi
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/blpapi/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    raise debug_load_error(error)
ImportError: No module named _versionhelper

Could not open the C++ SDK library.

Download and install the latest C++ SDK from:

    http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/api-library

If the C++ SDK is already installed, please ensure that the path to the library
was added to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH before entering the interpreter.
```

I recheck the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and it is set to the C/C++ SDK folder path \Users\hk\blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1

any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the C++ "lib" folder into your library path:

> \Users\hk\blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1\**lib**